# Making wordpress menu hover in color instead of blank

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I have a wordpress webpage using the theme 15zine. I would like to change the top menu so that it hovers to a color yellow. At the moment, it just goes blank when you hover. Here is the code:

```
}
#cb-top-menu ul li:hover > ul {
  top: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cb-top-menu ul li:hover > ul li > ul {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cb-top-menu ul li:hover > ul li:hover > ul {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
```

Comment: You're looking for the [`background-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) property.

Comment: That still doesn't appear to work..

Comment: Do you have try to add: `#cb-top-menu a:hover{background-color:yellow}`